# I can't connect to my wamp server from Android

Tags: android, apache

I am using 2.4.9 Apache, 5.5.12 Php, 5.6.17 MySql versions.

these are my properties in MainActivity.java :

```
private static String url_create_user = "http://myIPV4Address:8081/ytu/SignOn.php";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
```

in my onCreate function :

```
new CreateNewUser().execute();
```

in my CreateNewUser AsyncTask :

```
class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String display_name = "some Name";

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("display_name", display_name));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_user,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.w("success", "success");
            } else {
                Log.w("failed", "failed");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    }

}
```

and finally my JSONParser class :

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and my Android Manifest file is below :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application...
```

and I got these errors :

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.2.53:8081 refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
at sqlite.android.vogella.de.firstsqllite.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:54)
at sqlite.android.vogella.de.firstsqllite.MainActivity$CreateNewUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:254)
at sqlite.android.vogella.de.firstsqllite.MainActivity$CreateNewUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:217)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.2.53 (port 8081): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
... 15 more.
```

Edit 1 : and I also got these errors :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Edit 2 : I found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2933). It looks similar to my problem but I couldn't find the solution. Would it be the same problem with my problem?

Any help would be very nice.

Comment: Try shutting down your firewall, and make sure that the 8081 port is open.

Comment: I tried shutting down my firewall and I can connect to localhost:8081 wamp server home page. and I realized I also take another error which I updated in the question.

Comment: But I guess it is because connection was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

I added new rule for port 8081 in Windows Firewall setting and now it is working :)